# Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this .INF file?

Tags: deployment, installation, cab

I've been stuck on this all day, and have just run out of ideas.

I'm trying to run an installer from a CAB file initiated on a web page. I built a cab file that includes an installer (BlowbackInstaller.msi) and an inf file (see below).

**The Problem:** 
When I hit the web page in IE8, it correctly prompts me that a control is trying to install and shows the correct signature information, so I know it is finding the CAB file and it is signed.

Then it correctly prompts me about whether I want to install it.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cf19341e41.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cf19341e41.png)

After I press the install button, it just continues processing the page without running the installer. I know this because the installer has several dialogs in it.

I tested the installer (msi) separately and it works just fine, it just seems like it isn't being launched from the CAB by IE. I suspect a problem in my INF file.

**Here's the HTML to initiate it...**

```
<object id="bbc" 
        codebase="../cabs/BlowbackControl.cab"   
        classid="clsid:A4748756-061D-11DF-9D94-BD9455D89593">
    <param name="_ExtentX" value="26" />
    <param name="_ExtentY" value="26" />
</object>
```

**Here is the contents of the .inf file in the CAB.**

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0 

[Setup Hooks]
hook1=hook1

[hoook1]
run=msiexec.exe /i %EXTRACT_DIR%\BlowbackInstaller.msi
```

Anyone see something obvious I am missing, or have any ideas for troubleshooting further?

Comment: Is that supposed to be [hook1] at the bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [hoook1]

It wouldn't have something to do with the extra "o", would it?

Comment: DOH! I guess I am so used to seeing double that I must have missed that. Gotta stop drinking at work!